# Subspace of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V = M_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $W = \lbrace  A \in M_2(\mathbb{R}) : A = A^T\rbrace$.

Determine if $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

I am a bit confused about the vector space of $2\times 2$ matrices and how to start over with the transpose function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $A,B\in W$ and arbitrary scalars $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, then : \begin{align}(aA+bB)^T&=(aA)^T+(bB)^T\\ 
 &= a^TA^T+b^TB^T\\& = aA+bB\end{align}

so $aA+bB\in W$ and thus it is a vector subspace.